# Shutting down instance of Service Fabric stateless service

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have a Service Fabric stateless service that runs as a background job and reads from a queue. For each message it receives, it calls an external API.

If the failure rate is high for the external call, I want to bring down the specific instance of the service. If I can't process the messages, I don't want to read them from the queue.

What is the best way to shut down the instance from the RunAsync() method? I am throwing OperationCanceledException to bring the instance down, but is this the correct approach?

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  while (true)
  {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    if (/* error rate is high*/)
    {
      throw new OperationCanceledException();
    }
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown the service instance won't help with your problem.

Mainly because SF will bring it up again(restart) when the service shutdown without SF requesting it, and the service will start processing messages in less than a minute later. So, shutdown the service won't fix the problem.

The best way is handle these failures in the service is implementing a retry/back-off/circuit-breaker strategy to give more time between attempts or set a flag to suspend processing until a specific time.

The other alternative, is implement a monitoring service that remove services when these issues occur, this will in fact have the same effect you expect, but is probably more complex than just implementing in the code, because you will have to implement a notification in the service consuming the message, the monitor will listen for these events and then contact SF to shutdown the service, later, you have also the re-create the services to continue the processing, unless you really need to save the resources allocated to the services, this does not bring much benefit over in-service handling.

It all depends how complex it need to be.